# REGEXREPLACE last occurrence of a character

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to replace the last occurrence of `@` in a string on Google Sheets.

Right now I am using:

```
=trim(regexreplace(D6, "@", "From "))
```

but that replaces all of the @s in D6

If I had the following statement `@greg was here @sue`
I would like to have `@greg was here From sue` as an output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
=trim(regexreplace(C4, "(.*)@", "$1From "))
```

Or, if there are linebreaks:

```
=trim(regexreplace(C4, "(?s)(.*)@", "$1From "))
```

**Details**

- `(?s)` - makes a dot match across newlines
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any chars, 0 or more repetitions
- `@` - a `@` char.

The `$1` in the replacement pattern puts back the part of the string before the last `@` char.

Comment: Excellent solution and thank you! Worked like a charm